# Data Grid in HTML

Tags: html, css

How to Create a Data Grid using HTML Tags?

Comment: how to ask questions on stackoverflow http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 5):

you can use many javascript plugins like :

jquery :

1. http://www.datatables.net/
2. http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx

mootools :

1- https://github.com/mmurph211/Grid

about the implementation , usually its very easy html table

more helpfull posts :

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/

**update**

as [Stephen Chung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650891/stephen-chung) suggest : Ext-js has wonderfull demos but i am not sure about its license 
as far as i know its was free for personal use only , but its worth to mention it with DOJO and Closure as well 
http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/

Comment: Dojo and the Closure Library also have good grids.  And let's not forget Ext-Js!

Comment: I can't say enough good about datatables...it does everything a grid should and then some.  Also, keep a close eye on JQuery UI as they're adding a very well thought out grid that's themeroller compliant (as is datatables) very soon.